# what is proper monad or sequence comprehension to both map and carry state across?

Tags: scala, state, monads, state-monad

I'm writing a programming language interpreter.

I have need of the right code idiom to both evaluate a sequence of expressions to get a sequence of their values, and propagate state from one evaluator to the next to the next as the evaluations take place. I'd like a functional programming idiom for this.

It's not a fold because the results come out like a map. It's not a map because of the state prop across.

What I have is this code which I'm using to try to figure this out. Bear with a few lines of test rig first:

```
// test rig
class MonadLearning extends JUnit3Suite {

  val d = List("1", "2", "3") // some expressions to evaluate. 

  type ResType = Int 
  case class State(i : ResType) // trivial state for experiment purposes
  val initialState = State(0)

// my stub/dummy "eval" function...obviously the real one will be...real.
  def computeResultAndNewState(s : String, st : State) : (ResType, State) = {
    val State(i) = st
    val res = s.toInt + i
    val newStateInt = i + 1
    (res, State(newStateInt))
  }
```

My current solution. Uses a var which is updated as the body of the map is evaluated:

```
  def testTheVarWay() {
    var state = initialState
    val r = d.map {
      s =>
        {
          val (result, newState) = computeResultAndNewState(s, state)
          state = newState
          result
        }
    }
    println(r)
    println(state)
  }
```

I have what I consider unacceptable solutions using foldLeft which does what I call "bag it as you fold" idiom:

```
def testTheFoldWay() {

// This startFold thing, requires explicit type. That alone makes it muddy.
val startFold : (List[ResType], State) = (Nil, initialState)
val (r, state) = d.foldLeft(startFold) {
  case ((tail, st), s) => {
    val (r, ns) = computeResultAndNewState(s, st)
    (tail :+ r, ns) // we want a constant-time append here, not O(N). Or could Cons on front and reverse later
  }
}

println(r)
println(state)

}
```

I also have a couple of recursive variations (which are obvious, but also not clear or well motivated), one using streams which is almost tolerable:

```
def testTheStreamsWay() {
  lazy val states = initialState #:: resultStates // there are states
  lazy val args = d.toStream // there are arguments
  lazy val argPairs = args zip states // put them together
  lazy val resPairs : Stream[(ResType, State)] = argPairs.map{ case (d1, s1) => computeResultAndNewState(d1, s1) } // map across them
  lazy val (results , resultStates) = myUnzip(resPairs)// Note .unzip causes infinite loop. Had to write my own.

  lazy val r = results.toList
  lazy val finalState = resultStates.last

  println(r)
  println(finalState)
}
```

But, I can't figure out anything as compact or clear as the original 'var' solution above, which I'm willing to live with, but I think somebody who eats/drinks/sleeps monad idioms is going to just say ... use this... (Hopefully!)

Comment: Small aside, you want a constant time append, use Vector instead of List.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### With the map-with-accumulator combinator (the easy way)

The higher-order function you want is `mapAccumL`. It's in Haskell's [standard library](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html), but for Scala you'll have to use something like [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz).

First the imports (note that I'm using Scalaz 7 here; for previous versions you'd import `Scalaz._`):

```
import scalaz._, syntax.std.list._
```

And then it's a one-liner:

```
scala> d.mapAccumLeft(initialState, computeResultAndNewState)
res1: (State, List[ResType]) = (State(3),List(1, 3, 5))
```

Note that I've had to reverse the order of your evaluator's arguments and the return value tuple to match the signatures expected by `mapAccumLeft` (state first in both cases).

### With the state monad (the slightly less easy way)

As Petr Pudlák points out in another answer, you can also use the state monad to solve this problem. Scalaz actually provides a number of facilities that make working with the state monad much easier than the version in his answer suggests, and they won't fit in a comment, so I'm adding them here.

First of all, Scalaz does provide a `mapM`—it's just called `traverse` (which is a little more general, as Petr Pudlák notes in his comment). So assuming we've got the following (I'm using Scalaz 7 again here):

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

type ResType = Int
case class Container(i: ResType)

val initial = Container(0)
val d = List("1", "2", "3")

def compute(s: String): State[Container, ResType] = State {
  case Container(i) => (Container(i + 1), s.toInt + i)
}
```

We can write this:

```
d.traverse[({type L[X] = State[Container, X]})#L, ResType](compute).run(initial)
```

If you don't like the ugly type lambda, you can get rid of it like this:

```
type ContainerState[X] = State[Container, X]

d.traverse[ContainerState, ResType](compute).run(initial)
```

But it gets even better! Scalaz 7 gives you a version of `traverse` that's specialized for the state monad:

```
scala> d.traverseS(compute).run(initial)
res2: (Container, List[ResType]) = (Container(3),List(1, 3, 5))
```

And as if that wasn't enough, there's even a version with the `run` built in:

```
scala> d.runTraverseS(initial)(compute)
res3: (Container, List[ResType]) = (Container(3),List(1, 3, 5))
```

Still not as nice as the `mapAccumLeft` version, in my opinion, but pretty clean.

Comment: Sure I don't mind, your answer is much nicer. I saw the state monad there but I didn't know how to use it properly in Scala. Actually, in Haskell it's also called [traverse](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Traversable.html#v:traverse). The difference is that `mapM` works only on lists (and is easier to comprehend) whereas `traverse` on any [traversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Traversable.html) structure. (I was using Scalaz 6, is this Scalaz 7 only?)

Comment: Right—I'm adding a note about `traverse` (which has been in Scalaz as long as I've used it—it's just the `traverseS` stuff that's new).

Comment: I wish I could give you more than one upvote for bringing up `traverse` and `traverseS`... I had to run into haskell's `mapM` in somebody else's code to realize that's exactly waht I'm looking for.

Comment: The second you see a method with the following signature,

     def foo[A](s:State):(State,A) 

you know you should use a State monad.  State monads encapsulate the S => (S,A) behavior.  The really nice thing is that you can put them in a for comprehension, and they will execute sequentially and take care of passing the state from one to the next without you having to do it manually [http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz-day7] is a great example!

Answer (score 4):

What you're describing is a computation within the state monad. I believe that the answer to your question

> It's not a fold because the results come out like a map. It's not a map because of the state prop across.

is that it's **a monadic map using the state monad**.

Values of the state monad are  computations that read some internal state, possibly modify it, and return some value. It is often used in Haskell (see [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Advanced_monads#The_State_monad) or [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/State)).

For Scala, there is a `trait` in the ScalaZ library called [State](http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.4/doc/index.html#scalaz.State) that models it (see also [the source](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/State.scala)). There are utility methods in `States` for creating instances of `State`. Note that from the monadic point of view `State` is just a monadic *value*. This may seem confusing at first, because it's described by a function depending on a state. (A monadic function would be something of type `A => State[B]`.)

Next you need is a *monadic map* function that computes values of your expressions, threading the state through the computations. In Haskell, there is a library method [mapM](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:mapM) that does just that, when specialized to the state monad.

In Scala, there is no such library function (if it is, please correct me). But it's possible to create one. To give a full example:

```
import scalaz._;

object StateExample
  extends App
  with States /* utility methods */
{
  // The context that is threaded through the state.
  // In our case, it just maps variables to integer values.
  class Context(val map: Map[String,Int]);

  // An example that returns the requested variable's value
  // and increases it's value in the context.
  def eval(expression: String): State[Context,Int] =
    state((ctx: Context) => {
      val v = ctx.map.get(expression).getOrElse(0);
      (new Context(ctx.map + ((expression, v + 1)) ), v);
    });

  // Specialization of Haskell's mapM to our State monad.
  def mapState[S,A,B](f: A => State[S,B])(xs: Seq[A]): State[S,Seq[B]] =
    state((initState: S) => {
      var s = initState;
      // process the sequence, threading the state
      // through the computation
      val ys = for(x <- xs) yield { val r = f(x)(s); s = r._1; r._2 };
      // return the final state and the output result
      (s, ys);
    });


  // Example: Try to evaluate some variables, starting from an empty context.
  val expressions = Seq("x", "y", "y", "x", "z", "x");

  print( mapState(eval)(expressions) ! new Context(Map[String,Int]()) );
}
```

This way you can create simple functions that take some arguments and return `State` and then combine them into more complex ones by using `State.map` or `State.flatMap` (or perhaps better using `for` comprehensions), and then you can run the whole computation on a list of expressions by `mapM`.

---

See also http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/the-state-monad-for-scala-users/

---

**Edit:** See [Travis Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12265946/1333025)'s answer, he described how to use the state monad in Scala much more nicely.

He also asks:

> But why, when there's a standard combinator that does exactly what you need in this case?
>   (I ask this as someone who's been slapped for using the state monad when mapAccumL would do.)

It's because the original question asked:

> It's not a fold because the results come out like a map. It's not a map because of the state prop across.

and I believe the proper answer is **it is a monadic map using the state monad.**

Using `mapAccumL` is surely faster, both less memory and CPU overhead. But the state monad captures the concept of what is going on, the *essence of the problem.* I believe in many (if not most) cases this is more important. Once we realize the essence of the problem, we can either use the high-level concepts to nicely describe the solution (perhaps sacrificing speed/memory a little) or optimize it to be fast (or perhaps even manage to do both).

On the other hand, `mapAccumL` solves this particular problem, but doesn't give us a broader answer. If we need to modify it a little, it might happen it won't work any more. Or, if the library starts to be complex, the code can start to be messy and we won't know how to improve it, how to make the original idea clear again.

For example, in the case of evaluating stateful expressions, the library can become complicated and complex. But if we use the state monad, we can build the library around small functions, each taking some arguments and returning something like `State[Context,Result]`. These atomic computations can be combined to more complex ones using `flatMap` method or `for` comprehensions, and finally we'll construct the desired task. The principle will stay the same across the whole library, and the final task will also be something that returns `State[Context,Result]`.

To conclude: I'm not saying using the state monad is the best solution, and certainly it's not the fastest one. I just believe it is most didactic for a functional programmer - it describes the problem in a clean, abstract way.

Comment: But why, when there's a standard combinator that does exactly what you need in this case? (I ask this as someone who's been slapped for using the state monad when `mapAccumL` would do.)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a state monad version inspired by yours—I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this recursively:

```
def testTheRecWay(xs: Seq[String]) = {
  def innerTestTheRecWay(xs: Seq[String], priorState: State = initialState, result: Vector[ResType] = Vector()): Seq[ResType] = {
    xs match {
      case Nil => result
      case x :: tail =>
        val (res, newState) = computeResultAndNewState(x, priorState)
        innerTestTheRecWay(tail, newState, result :+ res)
    }
  }
  innerTestTheRecWay(xs)
}
```

Recursion is a common practice in functional programming and is most of the time easier to read, write and understand than loops. In fact scala does not have any loops other than `while`. `fold`, `map`, `flatMap`, `for` (which is just sugar for flatMap/map), etc. are all recursive.

This method is tail recursive and will be optimized by the compiler to not build a stack, so it is absolutely safe to use. You can add the @annotation.tailrec annotaion, to force the compiler to apply tail recursion elimination. If your method is not tailrec the compiler will then complain.

edit: renamed inner method to avoid ambiguity