# A hybrid of map and fold?

Tags: scala

Is there a function in Scala, which is a hybrid of map and fold? I'd like not to use a temporary var variable. I want to return a list and at the same time be able to have an accumulator.

**update:**

I'd like to do this

```
  def findMaxSubarray(source: Seq[Int]) = {
    var lastSum = 0
    val maxes = source map { x =>
      lastSum += x
      if (lastSum < 0) lastSum = 0
      lastSum
    }

    maxes.max
  }
```

without using `scalaz` and `var`, only using standard scala library.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261157/what-is-proper-monad-or-sequence-comprehension-to-both-map-and-carry-state-acros

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### For updated question

You could use `scanLeft` (or `scan`) like this:

```
val seq = Stream.continually(util.Random.nextInt(200) - 100).take(100)
val maxes = seq.scan(0){ (lastSum, i) => (lastSum + i) max 0 }
maxes.max
// Int = 547
```

It produces collection of all subresults of `foldLeft`

#### For initial question

There is such method in `scalaz`: `foldMap`.

```
(0 to 2).toList.foldMap{_ + 1}
// Int = 6
```

It works for monoids, `zero` is used as initial value:

```
(0 to 2).map{_ + 1}.fold(Monoid[Int].zero){_ |+| _}
```

There is no such method in standard scala library, but you could use `view` before `map` to avoid intermediate collection creation:

```
(0 to 2).view.map{_ + 1}.fold(0){_ + _}
```

Comment: what about the standard scala library?

Comment: but `fold(0){_ + _}` will return a single value, whereas I need a list.

Comment: @Alex A fold takes some collection and returns a single value. What do you expect from your fold? Sounds like you're just describing a map.

Comment: @Alex: please, add initial data and desired result to your question.

Comment: I think he needs a stateful map, but doesn't want to use a var outside the mapping function.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet: I guess I got it now: `map{i => val r = i + 1, tmp += r; r}`. Without reiterating over collection.

Comment: @Alex: In general you should use `map` and then `fold` unless you are sure that you have a bottleneck (and you have proved this with benchmarks).

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet: it's a typo. `tmp` should be `var`.