# How to replace values in one Seq with values from another Seq in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have sequences:

```
val A = Seq(1,3,0,4,2,0,7,0,6)
val B = Seq(8,9,10)
```

I need a new sequence where 0 are replaced with values from second sequence:

```
Seq(1,3,8,4,2,9,7,10,6)
```

How to do that in functional style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure that iterators are really functional. Anyway, here's an alternative

```
val A = Seq(1,3,0,4,2,0,7,0,6)  
val B = Seq(8,9,10)              
A.foldLeft((B, Seq[Int]())) {case ((b, r), e) => 
          if (e == 0 && ! b.isEmpty) (b.tail, b.head +: r) else (b, e +: r) }
   ._2.reverse
//> res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, 3, 8, 4, 2, 9, 7, 10, 6)
```

EDIT: Updated per the comment to leave the zeros if we're out of elements of B

EDIT2:

A pattern-matching variant is neater:

```
A.foldLeft((B, Seq[Int]())){case ((h +: t, r), 0) =>  (t, h +: r)
                            case ((b, r), e) => (b, e +: r)}
 ._2.reverse
```

And, based on [what is proper monad or sequence comprehension to both map and carry state across?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261157/what-is-proper-monad-or-sequence-comprehension-to-both-map-and-carry-state-acros)

```
A.mapAccumLeft(B, { case ((h +: t), 0) =>  (t, h)
                    case (b, e)  => (b, e) }
```

(probably, I don't have scalaz installed to test it)

Comment: If zeros are more than elements in B, then zeros stay, if less than elements in B then only first values from B are used. And yes, it seems that iterators are not functional.

Comment: Updated to handle running out of elements of B

Answer (score 8):

You can use `map` here, by replacing all 0s with the next element of `b` (by converting `b` to an iterator, and using `next`):

```
val a = Seq(1,3,0,4,2,0,7,0,6)
val b = Seq(8,9,10).iterator
a.map { e => if (e == 0) b.next else e } //Seq(1,3,8,4,2,9,7,10,6)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to look at Tail Recursion then this suits you.

```
@annotation.tailrec
  def f(l1: Seq[Int], l2: Seq[Int], res: Seq[Int] = Nil): Seq[Int] = {
    if (l1 == Nil) res
    else {
      if (l1.head == 0 && l2 != Nil) f(l1.tail, l2.tail, res :+ l2.head)
      else
        f(l1.tail, l2, res :+ l1.head)
    }
  }

val A = Seq(1, 3, 0, 4, 2, 0, 7, 0, 6)
val B = Seq(8, 9, 10)

scala> f(A,B)
res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, 3, 8, 4, 2, 9, 7, 10, 6)
```

if you run out of elements in B then ,

```
val A = Seq(1, 3, 0, 4, 2, 0, 7, 0, 6)
val B = Seq(8, 9)
scala> f(A,B)
res1: Seq[Int] = List(1, 3, 8, 4, 2, 9, 7, 0, 6)
```

if elements in A are less than B then,

```
val A = Seq(1, 0)
val B = Seq(8, 9, 10)
scala> f(A,B)
res2: Seq[Int] = List(1, 8)
```